# Update data in mongo Db using spring (MongoTemplate)

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a collection (A) which has two fields (String, integer) in mongoDB. I want to update the collection by adding some value to sting

Ex. Lets say i have a document A[field1 : ABC,field2 : 25]. I want to update it by adding ,say 5, to it so it will look like A[field1 :ABC,field2 : 30] after updation.

The code I have used for this is as follows:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("field1").is("ABC));
BeanName beanName = template.findOne(query, BeanName.class,collectionName);
if(null != beanName){
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("field1", "ABC");
    update.set("field2", beanName.getField2() + 5)
    template.updateFirst(query, update, BeanName.class,collectionName);
}
else{
    template.save(beanName, collectionName); // the value of filed1 and field 2 is populated in a bean with instance 'beanName'
}
```

The code is woriking fine with expected results but the performance is very slow. Is there any other efficient way for it.

I am working on large amount of data to update.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use findAndModify() method, in combination with the upsert = true feature. Please find the official documentation below :

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: This method wont let me to update on existing value. Is there any way to do so??

Comment: What do you mean ? The specification states "Modifies and returns a single document"